# Did Jack Torrance get arrested for assault against a minor before he became the caretaker?

Tags: movie, the-shining

Did [Jack Torrance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Torrance) from The Shining get charged for assaulting a minor before he became the caretaker at the Overlook hotel?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the book, it's strongly suggested that he wasn't charged with any criminal offence, presumably because he would have also had a pretty good case (for vandalism) against the boy that he hit. Regardless of the decision to avoid *legal* action, the boy was expelled and the School Board fired Jack.

I've edited + abridged for ease of reading;

> There was a boy named George Hatfield that Daddy had to cut from the
>   team. That means he wasn't as good as some of the others. George said
>   your daddy cut him because he didn't like him and not because he
>   wasn't good enough. Then George did a bad thing. I think you know
>   about that." “*Was he the one who put the holes in our bug's tires*?”
>   “*Yes, he was. It was after school and your daddy caught him doing
>   it*.”
>
> "*Something like that, honey. Your daddy hit George to make him stop
>   cutting the tires and George hit his head. Then the men who are in
>   charge of the school said that George couldn't go there anymore and
>   your daddy couldn't teach there anymore.*" She stopped, out of words,
>   and waited in dread for the deluge of questions. “*Oh*,” Danny said,
>   and went back to looking up the street. Apparently the subject was
>   closed.